# ASP.NET web form Authentication Roles not returned

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, web-config, asp.net-membership

I have an asp.net application which is only available if a user has access via Active Directory Group "Admin".  The app calls the Account/Login.aspx file if not authenticated.  I am having an issue where no roles are coming back from my Login after authentication.

Below is from my Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="10" path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionUsername="username" connectionPassword="password" connectionProtection="None" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true"/>
```

I put some code in my site.Master which displays the user and if in the role.

```
    lblUserName.Text = "Hello " + Context.User.Identity.Name + ".";
    lblAuthType.Text = "Is Admin? " + Context.User.IsInRole("Admin").ToString();
```

Return value is Hello Name Is Admin? False

When logging it the edits work fine as far as incorrect ID and password if entered.  Also, when debugging I look in the Context.User for Roles and the value is Blank.

Any help is appreciated.

---

***Follow Up per Response: ***

I plugged this in my web.config a

```
  <roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <add
          name="WindowsProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Code

> lblAuthType.Text = "Is Admin? " + Context.User.IsInRole("Admin").ToString();

**Error Message:**

Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity.

**Stack Trace**

```
[ProviderException: Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity.]
   System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider.GetCurrentWindowsIdentityAndCheckName(String userName) +2256845
   System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider.GetCurrentTokenAndCheckName(String userName) +36
   System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +61
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9864880
   DelegatePager.SiteMaster.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Source\IMS Web Internal\DelegatePager\DelegatePager\Site.Master.cs:55
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.OnInit(EventArgs e) +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +290
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +489
```

Comment: You need the WIndowsTokenRoleProvider configured... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I receive the message:  Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity..  in the config I have <identity impersonate="true"  />, and I turned this off and received the same message.

Comment: How exactly are they not matching if you're using the AD membership provider?

Comment: Erik,  Not sure why not matching.  I put in the code where exception occurs, as well as message and stack trace.

Comment: Also in the Config, If I put in <allow users="dk123"/> and I log in I am able to get to the screen.  When change back to <allow roles="Admin"/> error occurs.  Seems like whenever trying to pull back the Roles, issue occurs.